# I want to skip Permission Requested Interface at the time of login with Azure

Tags: php, azure-active-directory

I have implemented login with Azure successfully. 
When any user login 1st time , We get one “Permissions requested”  popup. 
Here user provide permission to particular Azure App . After that azure provide a code and using this code remaining process going on.

We want to skip “Permissions requested” popup .

> Is there any setting available by which App automatically get
>   permission and we can skip “Permissions requested”  popup ??

[image]

MY code :

```
$auth_url =  "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize" 
$client_id =  "<client_id>"; 
$redirect_uri = "<redirect_uri>"; 
$data = array(
'response_type' => 'code',
'client_id' => $client_id,
'scope' => 'User.Read',
'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri,
'response_mode' => 'query',
);              
$auth_redirect_url = $auth_url.'?'.http_build_query($data);
drupal_goto($auth_redirect_url); exit;
```

> I have also tried without passing scope or blank scope. It is display
>   some error

Comment: I think because of security reasons this popup shows up every time and you can't change it.

Comment: That's a consent popup and can't be avoided for security reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just navigate to the `Azure Active Directory` -> `App Registrations`  in the portal as a **global administrator**, click `Grant admin consent`. Then the app has been granted consent for all users, the page will not appear when login with a normal user.

[image]

Comment: After provide Grant admin consent , OTP validation off (Azure Multi-Factor Authentication).. How to enable OTP validation with Grant admin consent. ???